# SCOM 2016 PowerShell

Tags: shell, powershell, console, scom

I'm trying to package SCOM Console 2016 using Thinapp 5.2. The customer wants to use the PowerShell part of SCOM as well. But whenever i start SCOM Shell, it gives me a bunch of errors telling me that it can't find certain .dll files and more.

I have already tried installing it on a VM before but it gives me the same error messages, so Thinapp is not causing the errors.

Does anyone know where i should look?

```html
Import-Module : Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in C:\Program Files (x86)\System Center Operations Manager 2016\Powershell\OperationsManager\OM10.CoreCommands\Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Core.Cmdlets.dll because of the following error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.  Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Loader Exceptions:
Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Core, Version=7.0.5000.
, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.

At C:\Program Files (x86)\System Center Operations Manager 2016\Powershell\OperationsManager\OperationsManager.psm1:1261 char:14
    + Import-Module <<<<  $psScriptRoot\OM10.CoreCommands\OM10.CoreCommands.psd1
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Import-Module], PSSnapInException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSnapInLoadFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
 
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Systemcenter Operations Manager 2016\Powershell\OperationsManager\OM10.Commands\Microsoft.SystemCenter.OperationsManagerV10.Commands.dll or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded
At C:\Program Files (x86)\System Center Operations Manager 2016\Powershell\OperationsManager\OperationsManager.psm1:1262 char:14
    + Import-Module <<<<  $psScriptRoot\OM10.Commands\OM10.Commands.psd1
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], BadImageFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.BadImageFormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\System Center Operations Manager 2016\Console\Microsoft.Mom.Common.dll or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded
At C:\Program Files (x86)\System Center Operations Manager 2016\Powershell\OperationsManager\OperationsManager.psm1:1311 char:15
    + Add-Type <<<<  -Path $consoleMomCommon
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], BadImageFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.BadImageFormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it turned out we were using an old version of Windows Management Framework. After updating to version 5.1 all the errors were gone. I installed this update: KB3191566